# Using Netty for building own socket communication for IoT Hub or use MQTT?

Tags: mqtt, netty, iot

I am creating an IOT hub with Kotlin/Spring Boot and weighing the options for the TCP socket communication with the devices. At the moment I am planning to use Netty and build the socket communication protocol myself. At the same time I am thinking that I am developing something same as MQTT with MQTT broker already offers.

What I am looking for is some kind of nudge or points why to use MQTT instead of rolling out my own protocol.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is likely to lead to opinion based answers, Stack Overflow works for questions that have a single correct answer, not a discussion on the pros//cons of a situtation

Comment: What I will say is, what do you think you can do better than **all** the major cloud providers?

Comment: Fair point. This question is not properly formed.